# Create a new template view for a specific vocabulary name

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, panels

I'm in need of some help for my Drupal 7 site. Right now I am using the stock taxonomy view (/taxonomy/term/%) that came with views to display a listing of some specific nodes. It works great.

Now I would like to create another page that will display a different view listing of nodes under a different vocabulary term. I'd like to template to be different also.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to best do this. I am using Panels for some of my pages so could I use that? I've tried to activate the panels page that overrides the taxonomy, but I can't because I am using views already to generate a page. Can I clone my current view and set a filter for a specific vocabulary and use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Taxonomy Views Switcher](http://drupal.org/sandbox/simg/1106944) module which allowed me to create a new views page. It's not the best solution, but for me it works.